# When does $f\sim g$ implies $f'\sim g'$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, asymptotics

Given two $C^1$ functions $f,g:[0,+\infty)\to [0,+\infty)$ such that $f(x)\sim g(x)$ as $x\to\infty$, which good conditions guarantee that $f'(x)\sim g'(x)$?

I thought that monotonicity of the derivatives could be such condition, but I wasn't able to prove or disprove. I think that one such condition can be $f$, $f'$, $g$, $g'$, $f-g$ and $f'-g'$ to be monotonic increasing, but that's so restrictive that hurts.

Also, if anyone could suggest a book that treats problems like that (I don't know, "asymptotic analysis"?) I would appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you got an example of a $f$ and $g$ that this doesn't hold?

Comment: Maybe not the most interesting case, but if $f,g$ are polynomials then $f\sim_\infty g \implies f'\sim_\infty g'$ holds without any more conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Monotonicity of the derivatives is not enough. Let $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x+1}$ and $g(x)=1-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$.

Comment: Well pointed. Actually, that counterexample is even a little discouraging for a general solution. But the "core" of the problem in this seems to be that you took two functions of different growth orders and translated it by a constant. What if $f\to\infty$?

Comment: It is time to sleep here.  Will think about what can be said for $f\to\infty$. Tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

For solutions where $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ are finite,  I believe a good solution may be $(f(x)-\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x))\sim(g(x)-\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x))$

Comment: I added `\limits` since I personally find it easier to read, if you prefer limits set to the side, just remove the code

Comment: No problem! I'm not very good at formatting, as you can tell, so thanks for fixing it.